# Why is p[0]++ different from *(p)++ in C

Tags: arrays, pointers

When I tried to execute these codes in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
     int arr[] = {10, 20};
     int *p = arr; 
     p[0]++;   // *(p)++;
     printf("arr[0] = %d, arr[1] = %d",arr[0], arr[1]);
     return 0;
}
```

> output: arr[0] = 11, arr[1] = 20

on replacing `p[0]++;` by `*(p)++;`

> output : arr[0] = 10, arr[1] = 20

Please explain why this is. I know a[i] is equivalent to *(a + i)

Comment: Are you aware that the parentheses in `*(p)++` do nothing?

Comment: I think you wanted (*p)++

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
p[0]++;
```

basically increments the value at index 0.

While

```
*(p)++
```

Increments the pointer to the next address .

Example :

```
int arr = {10,20};

int *p = arr; // p points to the first element of array, i.e 10
*(p)++; // now p points to the next element i.e 20.
```

Answer (score 0):

below code can be used:

```
p[0]++ means = p[0] + 1;
p[0]++ = 10 + 1;
p[0]++ = 11;
```

You can't do with this same thing with an array, so be careful.

I hope it helps!